# How to use existing socket for a NodeJS HTTP server?

Tags: node.js, http

I made a proof of concept [Reverse HTTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-lentczner-rhttp-00) implementation using NodeJS.

However reusing client's socket required me to set a private member property; is there a correct way to do it?

```
server._socket = socket;
server.emit('connection', server._socket);
```

NodeJS HTTP docs tell about `server.listen(socket)`, but it didn't work; it threw an exception about illegal parameter.

Full sample code for both client & server available at: https://github.com/norjs/portal-service/blob/12-reverse-http-support/samples/reverse-http/client.js#L57

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm now trying to do the same, but with a TLS socket. Any hint/workaround? @thejhh

Comment: Nope. Still setting the private property. Although this is not in a production code. It ended up to be just a POC and never actually used it in anywhere.